# How to remove ASCII whitespace/eols from variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I've tried the following:

```
export PATH=>>-
$HOME/.cargo/bin:
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux:
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux:
$HOME/.dotnet:
$HOME/.android-ndk-r17b:
$PATH

export PATH=${PATH//$'\r'/}
export PATH=${PATH//$'\n'/}
export PATH=${PATH//$'\x20'/}
```

And still

```
-bash: /home/hydroper/.cargo/bin:: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/hydroper/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux:: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/hydroper/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux:: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/hydroper/.dotnet:: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/hydroper/.android-ndk-r17b:: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to think that the first line will start an expansion to the path. This is not true. The first line is a complete command.

```
export PATH= >> -
```

The line above, written with some spaces for better understanding, will set the `PATH` to an empty string, and append the output of the command to the file `-`.

The following line is the next command

```
$HOME/.cargo/bin:
```

This expands to the name of a directory that probably exists on your system, plus the colon. The result is

-bash: `/home/hydroper/.cargo/bin:`: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
export PATH="$(paste -sd : - << EOF
$HOME/.cargo/bin
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux
$HOME/.dotnet
$HOME/.android-ndk-r17b
$PATH
EOF
)"
```

`paste -s` is the command to join all the lines of a file (with the separator supplied with `-d`; `-` means *do it for stdin instead of an actual file*, `-` can be omitted with some implementations but that's not standard/portable).

To answer your question about removing whitespace, in `ksh93`/`mksh`, `bash` or `zsh`:

```
PATH=${PATH//[[:space:]]}
```

would remove all spacing characters, including ASCII ones, including the newline character. The list of matching characters depends on the locale and system (for instance, not all systems include the non-breaking-space), but all the ASCII ones (TAB, LF, VT, FF, CR, SPC) are always included.

To get that newline character into `$PATH` in the first place, you'd have needed:

```
export PATH="
$HOME/.cargo/bin:
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux:
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux:
$HOME/.dotnet:
$HOME/.android-ndk-r17b:
$PATH"
```

`>>` is an output redirection operator, you may be confusing with the `<<` or `<<-` here-doc operators. But even then, `<<` and `<<-` are to redirect input, so you'd still need to use it on a command that reads its input like `paste` in the example above and use command substitution (`$(...)` in the example above) for the output of that command to be passed as argument to `export`.

Note that you could also do:

```
export PATH="\
$HOME/.cargo/bin:\
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux:\
$HOME/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux:\
$HOME/.dotnet:\
$HOME/.android-ndk-r17b:\
$PATH"
```

Inside double quotes (and you do need the double quotes for those `$HOME` to be expanded), you can use `\` at the end of the line to break a long *logical* line into several *physical ones*. `$PATH` would *not* contain newline characters then, the `\<newline>` sequence is removed.

Or, outside quotes where `~` is expanded (including after `:` when in assignments) and `\<newline>` is also removed:

```
PATH=\
~/.cargo/bin:\
~/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux:\
~/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux:\
~/.dotnet:\
~/.android-ndk-r17b:\
$PATH
export PATH
```

(with `bash`, `export PATH=...`  would also work here, but not in all other shells).

In `zsh`, you could do:

```
path=(
   ~/.cargo/bin
   ~/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux
   ~/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux
   ~/.dotnet
   ~/.android-ndk-r17b
   $path
)
```

or

```
path[1,0]=(
   ~/.cargo/bin
   ~/.bkaradzic/bx/tools/bin/linux
   ~/.bkaradzic/bimg/tools/bin/linux
   ~/.dotnet
   ~/.android-ndk-r17b
)
```

as in `zsh`, the `$path` array is *tied* to the `$PATH` variable like in `csh` or `tcsh`.